# Rotating gaussian filter in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create and rotate gaussian filter in matlab. Here is my code:

```
function f = createGaussianArray(length, sigma, theta)
    half = length/2;
    [x,y] = meshgrid(-half:half, -half:half);
    x2 = cos(theta)*(x)-sin(theta)*(y);
    y2 = sin(theta)*(x)+cos(theta)*(x);
    matrix = exp(- (x2.^2+y2.^2) / (2*sigma.^2));
    f = matrix ./ sum(matrix(:));
end
```

When I call this function(function is in gauss.m file):

```
filter = gauss(31, 10, pi/2);
imagesc(filter)
```

It works well for pi/3, pi/6 vs. However when I send 3pi/4, 0, pi or 2*pi as an argument, It displays only a straight line. What is wrong with my code, I did not understand.

Answer (score 1):

The rotation transform is:

```
x2 = cos(theta)*(x)-sin(theta)*(y);
y2 = sin(theta)*(x)+cos(theta)*(y);  % last term is not cos(theta)*(x)
```

Comment: when i do this it does not rotate, gaussian filter remains the same for any theta value

Comment: @otp Are you trying to rotate the kernel? The gaussian filter itself it radially symmetric.